# Application Launch High Res Image

Tags: iphone, ios4

In the apple docs it states

> The  portion is the
>   optional string @2x and should be
>   included only on images intended for
>   use on high-resolution screens

What are high-resolution screens? iPhone 4's? Do I need to include one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed the part where the iPhone 4 and it's double high resolution screen was introduced :-)

The iPhone 4 screen is 640 by 960.

To automatically take advantage of that you can provide graphics assets that have that `@2x` in the name.

When you use something like `UIImage#imageNamed:`, the OS will automatically use the high resolution image if appropriate.

It will also use those for the icons and launch screens if available.

They are all *optional* though. But I'm sure your users with an iPhone 4 will appreciate the high res artwork :-)

Comment: So, if you have one image called `background.png` 40px by 40px, you should also provide an image called `background@2x.png` 80px by 80px, to give your iPhone 4 users the best experience of your app.

Comment: BUT you should still use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]`, because the iPhone automatically finds the @2x-version if it's being run at a high-res screen (iPhone 4).